# EXTJS 4 Grid selection model row

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid and when I click on a button in the toolbar of the panel I want to check if a row in the grid is selected.
If true I need de value of one cell of that row, so I can put it behind a url.

But I have no idea how I can use the selection model to get the cell value of a selected row in EXT JS 4.

Comment: get the cell render value or dataIndex(field) value?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try something like:

```
grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()
```

This will return an array of all selected records withing the grid.

Then,  you can iterate over the selection, find your row and call `row.get('PropName')` to get the value.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching the issue backwards though. You want to register for the 'selectionchange' event from the grid.

```
thisController.control ({'#mygrid': 
{
 selectionchange:onSelectionChange}
});

function:onSelectionChange(model, selected, eOpts )
{
//do work here
}
```

So basically you want to create an event driven model.